# DHCP not assigning IP to network interface

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

Running dhcpd from CLI with configuration file on `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`, returns:

```
No subnet declaration for enp2s0 (no IPv4 addresses).
** Ignoring requests on enp2s0.  If this is not what
   you want, please write a subnet declaration
   in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
   to which interface enp2s0 is attached. **


Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
```

but i can't really get how is this configuration "*write a subnet declaration in your dhcpd.conf file*" supposed to be. My config file is the following:

```
# minimal sample /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
subnet 192.166.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.166.1.150 192.166.1.200;
}
#on a request by the dhcp client, the dhcp server gives those net parameters.
```

The laptop is connected to a switch, that does not have any dhcp. Any help on setting up DHCP server?

Comment: How do/can you choose IP 192.166...? What's the IP of your gateway?

Comment: there is  no gateway just 2 PCs connected to a switch @Dri372

Comment: You don't have.want/acces to the web? Just have this 2 PCs to communicate together?

Comment: Yes, and then I will move on, but step by step @Dri372. There will be more PCs that's why I want DHCP.

Comment: Ok understood. But there must have always a gateway :-) In your case it's the PC where you define your DCHP server. How do you setup your network on this PC?

Comment: @Dri372 Right, but how should I indicate the pc IP, if it's supposed to be assigned by dhcp?

Comment: No it's 2 different things; you should find an answer with this search 'how to setup a fixed IP?' and if you don't succeed ask another question on so.

Comment: So the gateway will be my ethernet card IP after it is assigned? it's going better thanks a lot @Dri372. My network config is done using netplan

Comment: Yes but I don't use netplan. Which OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DHCP server must be setup on a host with a network already configured.

It does not assign the IP for the host it is running on.

So first you have to defined a fixed IP for this host. Then this fixed IP will be the gateway IP for the other PCs you will connect.

Note : as soon as you know how to setup a fixed IP , you have better to begin your test without dhcp server at all, that means by setting also a fixed IP on the same network for the second PC.

Comment: Thank you for helping.

Comment: The pc where I manually assign IP has no gateway?

Comment: Hi @sheldrake A gateway is a "door on a network", your first PC is alone and is alreeady in its network, no need a door to enter where you are.